# Probability of two fair coin toss

Tags: probability

A player tosses two fair coins in a game. The game ends if both coins show heads or both show tails. Otherwise, the two coins are tossed again and the game ends after the second toss. Find the probability of getting $0$ heads, $1$ head, $2$ heads and $3$ heads respectively.

I was able to derive the answer for everything except for $2$ heads. The answer was $\frac{1}{2}$. The answer solved it using the complement method, which I understand. However, when I tried solving for $\frac{1}{2}$ by finding all the possible combinations, I couldn't get the answer. Can anyone guide me for this question? Thank you in advance!

Comment: "*When I tried solving by finding all the possible combinations...*"  Show us exactly what you tried with numbers.  Remember that to get one head out of two tosses, this could have been HT or it could have been TH.  Remember that to get two heads overall, you could have had it that you just get two heads in the first round and not go to a second round, or you could have had one head in the first round and one head in the second round.

Comment: You *should* have gotten $\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$ as expected.

Comment: Ah I see, I understand now. Thank you so much for your help! Really appreciate it :)